# Problem about finding the percentages of men and women working at a company according to their average salaries

Tags: algebra-precalculus, means

I am stuck on this problem on the topic of statistics because I don't understand how these kinds of problems are solved.
If someone could explain it to me that would be a great help.

The average monthly salary paid to all employees of a company is \$5,000. Male employees receive an average of \$5,200 and female employees an average of \$4,200. Estimate the percentage of men and women working at the company.

**Attempt:**  The total amount paid each month by the company I think it would be something like this: $X =$ amount of men, $Y =$ amount of women, then $5200X + 4200Y = 5000(X+Y)$. From that I get $X = 4Y$ but I need a second equation to substitute one of the variables, is this right or am I mistaken?

Comment: Nothing about statistics, this is just basic algebra. Hint: what is the total of all salaries paid each month.

Comment: @dxiv Hi, thanks for answering. The total amount paid each month by the company I think it would be something like this: X = amount of men, Y = amount of women, then 5200*X + 4200*Y = 5000*(X+Y). From that I get X = 4*Y but I need a second equation to substitute one of the variables, is this right or am I mistaken?

Comment: @dxiv Now I realize that I can use that outcome to answer the problem, sense the amount of men is equal to four times the amount of women, then I can say that at the company there is 20% male and 80% female employees. Is this correct?

Comment: You've got the percentages swapped at the very end, but other than that it's corect.

Comment: @dxiv Oh you're right, my bad, it is the other way around. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt.  The attempt should be included in the question itself rather than the comments, where it might be overlooked.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oh sorry you are right, luckily another person already added a complete answer and I marked it as the answer to my post. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \$5,000$ be the average wage for this company. Denote $X$ the average salary of male employees and $Y$ the average salary of female employees. Since they all tend to the statistical average, we can write:
\begin{align}
5,200 \times X + 4,200 \times Y = 5,000 \times (X+Y)\\
\implies X = 4Y
\end{align}
(avoided elementary number algebra, but if you are unsure I can also add that in later). Thus, the average number of males in this company is four times the number of females. In percentage style, we can write that as
\begin{align}
80\% \ \text{men and} \ 20\% \ \text{women}.
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for explaining the exercise to me, your answer is completely clear and I learned the general way to solve these kinds of problems thanks to you and @dxiv. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: If you were looking for a second equation in order to solve the $2x2$ linear system, you could also take into account the statistical fact that the number of men and women in the company add to $100 \%$, that is you have the system
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
X=4Y\\
X+Y=1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I am only writing this because I would expect your teacher to ask you where you got the percentage from. It might sound trivial, but it really is not.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me a lot.